# unable to kill user-session with loginctl

Tags: lubuntu, session, sddm

I'm running lubuntu 20.04 with sddm as display-manager.

Whenever I logout over gui and login as a different user the  user-session is not be killed (do not know if it is by-design). So loginctl shows me doupple sessions for my users.

All sessions from my 2. user I killed with

```
killall -u second_user_name
```

for my main user 3 sessions remains.

The session with the lowerst session id i could remove with

```
sudo loginctl kill-session 3
```

Leftover

```
loginctl list-sessions 
SESSION  UID USER SEAT  TTY
     11 1000 alex seat0    
     21 1000 alex seat0
```

Next try

```
alex@Guilmon:~$ sudo loginctl kill-session 11
[sudo] Passwort für alex:
```

```
alex@Guilmon:~$ loginctl list-sessions 
SESSION  UID USER SEAT  TTY
     11 1000 alex seat0    
     21 1000 alex seat0    

2 sessions listed.
alex@Guilmon:~$ 


How can I get rid of it? Or avoid this situation (more than one session per user)
```

Comment: I'm unsure what you meant with "*logout over gui*", but I created a new user 'blah' on a QA-test system (*impish* as that's the last thing we were QA-testing & thus what I currently have handy) and could not re-create this issue on *impish* (21.10). I may not get to try it today on *focal*...

Comment: Okay, I do see it using a *focal* live system... I don't have time to explore further currently sorry

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think I found out to avoid this situation.
In

```
/etc/systemd/logind.conf

KillUserProcesses=yes
```

From manpage

```
KillUserProcesses=
           Takes a boolean argument. Configures whether the processes of a user should be killed when the user logs out. If true, the scope unit
           corresponding to the session and all processes inside that scope will be terminated. If false, the scope is "abandoned", see
           systemd.scope(5), and processes are not killed. Defaults to "no", but see the options KillOnlyUsers= and KillExcludeUsers= below.

           In addition to session processes, user process may run under the user manager unit user@.service. Depending on the linger settings, this may
           allow users to run processes independent of their login sessions. See the description of enable-linger in loginctl(1).

           Note that setting KillUserProcesses=yes will break tools like screen(1) and tmux(1), unless they are moved out of the session scope. See
           example in systemd-run(1).
```

```
I restart
```

```
    sudo systemctl restart systemd-logind.service
```

after logout 1. user and logged in to 2. user and back

```
alex@Guilmon:~$ loginctl 
SESSION  UID USER SEAT  TTY
     15 1000 alex seat0    

1 sessions listed.
alex@Guilmon:~$
```

No longer waiting for stopping something from abandoned user session during shutdown or restart.